# unable to reload same state on page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have created SPA with *angular v1.5.6* and *angular-ui-router v1.0.0alpha0*; Here is my [**`Working Plunker`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AcQk0Zrik1RjgXL4qLSm?p=preview) .
in this SPA I have 3 page : landing page i.e. **"/"**, **/Home** and **/About** . Home page required login ; after login we save credentials in local Storage so that on refresh of page we do not lose the page. everything is working fine but now I have issue on **/Home** page

when I refresh the **/Home** page , it gives below error for the property which is defined in *data* attribute of *.state* and page do not load

> angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property *'authorizedRoles'* of undefined

route is defined in below way ( only relevant code shown below)

```
 $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: './home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            requiresAuth: true,
            data : { pageTitle : 'Home', authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.admin, USER_ROLES.editor] }
        })
```

and using below code in `*.config*` which are the cause of error

```
$transitionsProvider.onBefore({to: function(state) { return state.requiresAuth; } },
        function($transition$, $state, AuthService) {
            console.log(arguments);
            var from = $transition$.to().name;
            console.log(from);
            if(!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                return $state.go("login", {referral : from});
            } else {
                console.log('I m logged in');
                var roles = $state.current.data.authorizedRoles;
                if(AuthService.isAuthorized(roles)) {
                    console.log('Authorized');
                }
            }
    });
```

*note:* write any credentials in that plunker when asking for login.

after page refresh $state.current goes blank ; how to handle this situtaions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with this [help from github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2852)

`var roles = $state.current.data.authorizedRoles;`

will be

`var roles = $transition$.to().data.authorizedRoles;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `dev tool`?

Put a breakpoint in `app.js:76` and click `Home`, you will see that your current state is base state which does not have `data` property.

Comment: Yes. I find that seem valid but why this happens when we refresh the same Home page